# How to find American Mathematical Society Translations: Series 2 Volume 12 published in 1959

Tags: journals

I am interested in an article in this book: Calculation of the Amount of Information about a Random Function Contained in Another Such Function.

I tried my University library, google scholar, AMS website. But still couldn't find this book. The ISBN is 1399884948. Is there a place I can get old journal papers?

Comment: Your university library should be able to acquire it via interlibrary loan, and if they can't, they should be able to tell you what the difficulty is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a link to the scanned article at Google Books:

http://tinyurl.com/pywo7dw